# How to plot lines and dots in the same plot while using different sized data

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

This toy data frame represents my data.

```
        Time    Gene     Value
   1      0      A         1
   2      1      A         2
   3      2      A         3
   4      0      B         1 
   5      1.2    B         2 
   6      1.7    B         2 
   7      2.1    B         2 
   8      3      B         2
```

Using the following code I can turn this into a line plot with two lines, one for A and one for B.

```
ggplot(data=Data, aes(x=Time, y=Value, group=Gene)) +
geom_line(aes(color=Gene), linetype="longdash", size=2)+
theme_classic()+
labs(title= paste("Genes over time course"),
     x="Time",
     y="Expression")+
theme(plot.title=element_text(size=20, face="bold",hjust = 0.5), 
      axis.text.x=element_text(size=10), 
      axis.text.y=element_text(size=10),
      axis.title.x=element_text(size=15),
      axis.title.y=element_text(size=15),
      legend.text=element_text(size=10))
```

However, I would like Gene A to be represented by only dots, and Gene B to be represented by only a line. How can I accomplish this given the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `data=~subset(., ...)` we can control which data goes to each layer.

```r
ggplot(Data, aes(x = Time, y = Value, color = Gene, group = Gene)) +
  geom_line(data = ~ subset(., Gene != "A")) +
  geom_point(data = ~ subset(., Gene == "A"))
```

[image: ggplot geom points and lines]

(You can also use `dplyr::select` in place of `subset`, the results are the same.)